# Group by and "first" or "min"

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a table "messages" with the columns id,from,to,datetime,subject,body. I want to get subject and body of the latest message for each sender (from).

Here is my query

```
SELECT min(subject) as tsubject,min(body) as tbody 
FROM messages 
WHERE "to"=28
GROUP BY "from"
ORDER BY "datetime"
```

This will result in

```
ERROR:  column "messages.datetime" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

So i get what the error is all about, but i don't want to group the result by "datetime", just the groups to be sorted so min picks the latest message from every group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*,u.name,m.subject,m.body FROM
(SELECT "from",max("datetime") as sent
FROM messages 
WHERE "to" = 31
GROUP BY "from") a
LEFT JOIN users u ON a."from" = u.id
LEFT JOIN messages m ON a.sent=m."datetime" AND a."from"=m."from"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select subject, body, m."from"
from (
    SELECT 
        id,
        "from",
        max("datetime")
    FROM messages 
    WHERE "to" = 28
    group by id, "from"
    ) s 
    inner join 
    messages m on m.id = s.id
ORDER BY "datetime" desc
```

Comment: After trying it out properly, it turned out it doesn't actually group by "from".